# lookup on all documents inside an array - MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I need to execute a lookup stage on all documents inside an array.

The collection:

```
{
  {
    "name": "test",
    "age": 2,
    "replies": [
        {
            "title": "testtt",
            "merta_id": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "testiona",
            "merta_id": 5
        },
        {
            "title": "the thirth test",
            "merta_id": 4
        }
    ]
    
  }
}
```

The `mertas` collection:

```
{
  {
     _id: 1,
     a: "aaaa",
     b: "bbbb"
  },
  {
     _id: 5,
     a: "AaAA",
     b: "BbbB"
  },
    {
     _id: 4,
     a: "Aou",
     b: "Boo"
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  {
    "name": "test",
    "age": 2,
    "replies": [
        {
            "title": "testtt",
            "merta_id": 1,
            "merta": {
                 _id: 1,
                 a: "aaaa",
                 b: "bbbb"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "testiona",
            "merta_id": 5,
            "merta": {
                 _id: 5,
                 a: "aaaa",
                 b: "bbbb"
             }
        },
        {
            "title": "the thirth test",
            "merta_id": 4
            "merta":{
                  _id: 4,
                  a: "Aou",
                  b: "Boo"
              }
        }
    ]

  }
}
```

I need an aggregation stage to execute a lookup on all documents on "replies" and add a new `merta` field, which should lookup from `mertas` collection.
I tried to use `$map` stage, but got the error "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'"

Comment: Show your `mertas` collection document and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$replies" },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "mertas",
        "localField": "replies.merta_id",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "replies.merta"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$replies.merta" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
        "replies": { "$push": "$replies" }
    }},
    { "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": {
            "$mergeObjects": ["$data", { "replies": "$replies" }]
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Above query have some mistake, Please remove $ sign in lookup with field. Because field value use without $ sign  in lookup keyword.

Comment: I guess `$_id:$_id` should be `_id:$_id` inside group

Comment: @saketh hmm One more. Actually Wrote the script on hand on the editor without testing. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks, it's almost working. but name and age fields are lost, the final result only have a replies field. (in my real collection, i have many fields beside of `replies`, and i don't have the list of them). @Ashh